# Terminología en DOM: ¿qué es un objeto?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente duda a nivel teórico:

¿Qué es exactamente un objeto? Es que, por lo que estoy leyendo acerca del Modelo de Objetos (DOM), no queda muy claro si un objeto es una variable de tipo objeto, o si es equivalente a un nodo, o si es un tipo de nodo (por ejemplo, un button sería un objeto y un nodo; sin embargo, un atributo no sería un objeto pero sí un nodo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Javascript (y en otros muchos lenguajes orientados a objetos) todos los objetos pertenecen a una clase. Y todas las clases son hijas (heredan) de la clase Object:

```js
let array = [1,2];
let obj = {};

console.log(array instanceof Array);
console.log(array instanceof Object);

console.log(obj instanceof Object);
```

Por tanto, un botón en un documento HTML, al ser representado en el DOM como una instancia de la clase `HTMLButtonElement`, es un objeto. Y lo mismo pasa con todos y cada uno de los elementos del DOM.
Un atributo de un objeto/nodo puede ser a su vez un objeto. Pero recuerda: en Javascript no todo es un objeto, hay tipos básicos (`number`, `string`, `boolean`) que no son objetos:

```js
const obj1 = {
  atributo1: [1,2]
};

console.log(obj1.atributo1 instanceof Array);
```

```js
const boton = document.querySelector('button');

console.log(boton instanceof HTMLButtonElement);
const clases = boton.classList;
console.log(clases instanceof DOMTokenList);
console.log(clases[0]);
console.log(clases[0] instanceof Object);
console.log(typeof clases[0]);
```

```html
<button class="clase-demo">Botón de prueba</button>
```

Comment: Perfectamente explicado. No puedo añadir nada más al respecto.

Muchísimas gracias @Pablo

Answer (score 4):

En programación orientada a objetos sabrás que un objeto s una instancia de una clase.
Supongo que habrás leído que Javascript usa la programación orientada a objetos de forma un poco particular. A efectos prácticos este lenguaje puedes ver un objeto como una colección de propiedades y métodos, y si te fijas para Javascript prácticamente todo son objetos: strings, arrays, numbers, ....
Y el DOM sigue en la misma línea: todos los elementos se usan como objetos. Por ejemplo un bloque div es un nodo en el árbol del DOM, y se gestiona desde javascript como un objeto con sus métodos y propiedades.
Espero que te aclare la duda, o al menos no te líe más :)

Comment: Buenas!

Entiendo lo que quieres decir. Entonces, cuando hacen referencia a un nodo tipo element, ¿todos los elements son objetos? Y, respecto al resto (comentarios, atributos, el propio texto plano, etc.) ¿son objetos? Porque puedes convertirlos también en variables, con sus propiedades y métodos asociados

Gracias por la respuesta :)

Comment: Los elemento de la página son tratados como objetos por javascript. Por ejemplo un bloque div contiene atributos como class o id o style. para javascript ese nodo es un objeto y class, id o style son propiedades,  En este ejemplos style es a su vez un objeto. Un texto lo lees como una string, y el string es un objeto.